# Differential dependence on parametres - error estimate

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Consider the parametrized IVP $$ x'=t+ \mu x^2, \quad x(0)=0.$$

Since the right-hand side is locally Lipschitz in $x$ for all $t$ and $\mu$, we have, for each $\mu$, a unique solution; denote it by $x(t,\mu)$.

There's no explicit formula for $x(t,\mu)$; however, we have $x(t,0)=t^2/2$. Moreover, solving equation of variation, we get that
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \mu}(t,\mu) = \int\limits_0^t x^2(\tau,\mu) \exp\left(\int\limits_\tau^t 2x(s, \mu) \mu \, ds \right)d\tau.
$$
Plugging in $\mu = 0$, we get
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial \mu}(t, 0) = \int\limits_0^t \frac{\tau^4}{4} \, d\tau = \frac{t^5}{20}.
$$
The problem I'm trying to solve asks now to estimate
$$
\sup\limits_{t,\mu \in [0,1]^2}\left|x(t,\mu) - x(t, 0) - \mu \frac{\partial x}{\partial \mu}(t,0)\right|.
$$
This is equivalent to calculating the error of linear approximation of $x(t,\mu)$ in $\mu$ for a fixed $t$. However, we would need to calculate (and estimate) $\partial ^2 x / \partial \mu^2$, which seems tedious. Is there some "clever" approach to this estimation?

Comment: I'd probably write out $x(t, \mu+h)-x(t, \mu)$ as an integral and then Taylor $f$. If I'm not mistaken, this should give you an integral equation for the derivative.